# Error: En la inserción a una tabla con INSERT... EXEC en SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

El script que se detalla líneas abajo arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Mens 8164, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIOLIBRE, Línea 23
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
Mens 8164, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIOLIBRE, Línea 27
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
```

Donde un store procedure mayor `(PR_MAIN)` llama al otro store `(PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO)`. Este último hace una consulta en las vistas del sistemas tales como `sysfiles`, `sys.master_files`, `sys.databases` y un par de inserciones haciendo uso del `insert ... exec...`. Según leía al parecer el problema viene por ese lado, también hay un caso muy parecido en este foro y no he encontrado una solución concreta ya que al parecer encontró la solución haciendo uso de una variable tipo tabla en mi caso no puedo insertar aunque cree una tabla temporal.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE PR_MAIN

    @VAR SYSNAME = null

    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON

            IF (@VAR = 'C')
                EXEC PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO

            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF (@VAR_UNID IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                    -- Se declara la variable tipo @TB_REPORT
                    DECLARE @TB_REPORT TABLE
                    (
                        NAME_BD     SYSNAME,
                        NAME_LOG    SYSNAME,
                        UNIDAD      CHAR,
                        ESP_ASIG    DECIMAL(15,2),
                        ESP_USA     DECIMAL(15,2),
                        ESP_DISP    DECIMAL(15,2),
                        FREEMB      INT
                    )

                    -- Inserción del resultado de PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO en @TB_REPORT
                    INSERT @TB_REPORT
                    EXEC PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO 0
                    -- Error: Por anidar el INSERT y el EXEC

                END
                ELSE PRINT 'El Parámatro ingresado no coincide con ninguno de los criterios establecidos'

            END

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

    GO
```

Al parecer una de las soluciones que se plantea en la red es hacer uso de funciones con salida tipo tabla (por favor expliquen un caso práctico) o involucrando la función `OPENROWSET`. Este último lo entiendo menos. De lo contrario voy a tener que "desempaquetar" el código de dicho store `(PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO)` dentro del `PR_MAIN` y es lo que no quiero.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar qué contiene `EXEC PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO`? la verdad no creo que así puedas ejecutar ese `INSERT`. Prueba dejando la lógica del sp `PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO` dentro del sp `PR_MAIN`.

Comment: No creí necesario poner la lógica por ser extensa y por que creo que no hace  falta para solucionar el problema ya que por separado si funciona y los campos que arroja son los que se definen en la variable tipo tabla.

Comment: Seguramente `PR_CONSULTA_ESPACIO ` inserta en una tabla y luego devuelves esos registros para que `PR_MAIN` los vuelva a insertar en otra tabla. Eso no funciona en SQL server no puedes anidar inserts, tan simple como eso, debes buscar otro tipo de solución.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente lo que seguramente está sucediendo es que estás "anidando" al menos dos cláusulas del tipo `INSERT ... EXEC`. Un ejemplo simple para explicar el problema podría ser el siguiente escenario:

```
SP_OUTER <- Tiene un EXEC..INSERT
+--> SP_INNER <- Tiene un EXEC..INSERT
     +--> SP_MOST_INNER <- Retorna un recordset
```

En este ejemplo llamamos a `SP_OUTER` el cual invoca a `SP_INNER` y recupera e inserta los datos que devuelve el último en una tabla usando una cláusula `EXEC..INSERT`, pero `SP_INNER` a su vez hace algo parecido, invoca a `SP_MOST_INNER` y recupera los datos con otra clausula `EXEC..INSERT`. Es decir estamos "anidando" dos `EXEC..INSERT`, esto no es posible hacerlo en SQL Server.

Este sería una demostración de lo comentado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MOST_INNER
AS
    DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,VALOR VARCHAR(255))
    INSERT INTO @T (VALOR) VALUES ('PRUEBA')
    SELECT * FROM   @T

RETURN 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INNER
AS
    DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, VALOR VARCHAR(255))
    INSERT INTO @T (ID, VALOR)
        EXEC SP_MOST_INNER
    UPDATE  @T
        SET VALOR = VALOR + '->[SP_INNER]'
    SELECT * FROM   @T

RETURN 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_OUTER
AS
    DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, VALOR VARCHAR(255))
    INSERT INTO @T (ID, VALOR)
        EXEC SP_INNER
    UPDATE  @T
        SET VALOR = VALOR + '->[SP_OUTER]'
    SELECT  ID,VALOR FROM   @T

RETURN 0
GO

-- Esta llamada dará un error: An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested    
EXEC SP_OUTER

DROP PROCEDURE SP_MOST_INNER
DROP PROCEDURE SP_INNER
DROP PROCEDURE SP_OUTER
GO
```

Nota: Obviamente cada SP, agrega lógica adicional en el tratamiento de los datos (en este ejemplo las sentencias de `UPDATE`), sino no tendría sentido llamar a tantos Sps.

#### ¿Como solucionar este problema?

Hay muchas formas, [este documento](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) explica varias formas de intercambiar datos entre distintos Sp´s. Yo te sugiero que una buena forma es trabajar con una única tabla temporal, y que cada SP trabaje sobre la misma y evitar más de un `EXEC..INSERT`. El problema que tiene esto es que lamentablemente hay que modificar la lógica de al menos los dos últimos Sp´s.

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MOST_INNER
AS
    DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,VALOR VARCHAR(255))
    INSERT INTO @T (VALOR) VALUES ('PRUEBA')
    SELECT * FROM   @T

RETURN 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INNER
AS
    INSERT INTO #t (ID, VALOR)
        EXEC SP_MOST_INNER
    UPDATE  #t
        SET VALOR = VALOR + '->[SP_INNER]'

RETURN 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_OUTER
AS
    CREATE TABLE #t  (ID INT, VALOR VARCHAR(255))

    EXEC SP_INNER

    UPDATE  #t
        SET VALOR = VALOR + '->[SP_OUTER]'

    SELECT  ID,VALOR FROM #t

RETURN 0
GO
EXEC SP_OUTER


DROP PROCEDURE SP_MOST_INNER
DROP PROCEDURE SP_INNER
DROP PROCEDURE SP_OUTER
GO
```

En este ejemplo, `SP_OUTER` crea una tabla temporal de sesión `#t` la cual es completada inicialmente por `SP_INNER`, al estar todo en un mismo "scope" `SP_INNER` "ve" la tabla `#t` y puede insertar los registros directamente, en este caso con el único `EXEC..INSERT` que dejamos para que no nos de el error. De esta forma nos sacamos de encima uno de los `EXEC..INSERT`, con esto dejamos intacto el sp más profundo `SP_MOST_INNER`, pero el alcance de la tabla `#t` al invocar de esta forma los Sp´s,  abarca hasta el último de ellos, por lo que podríamos modificar `SP_MOST_INNER` para que inserte directamente lor registros y no los retorne mediante un `SELECT`, con lo que podríamos evitar todos los `EXEC..INSERT`.